# "Motion" video motion detecting software framerate issues

Tags: raspberry-pi, motion

I am trying to configure motion (https://motion-project.github.io/) to record video files.

No matter what value I set the `framerate` option the video files that are created all appear to have a framerate of between 1 and 2 FPS.

I am running on a Raspberry Pi Zero. Is it possible that the frame rate is being throttled or limited by available memory or processor speed of raspi zero?

Anyone have any insight into this issue?

Here is my config file: https://pastebin.com/28teAEiJ

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the package of motion that supports MMAL? According to this thread titled: [Motion/MMAL/Jessie](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=140417) it sounds like the Pi just can't handle the frame rate.

> Your resolution question is a bit more complicated. The clever part of this version of motion is that the Pi's camera feeds low resolution video to the motion detection algorithm - so that the Pi's processor isn't too heavily loaded - and at the same time, higher resolution stills and videos of the detected movement can be saved. So you need to have a good look at your config file to get the resolution you want. These are the key lines in the config

The example config shows the framerate of 4:

```
width 320
height 188
framerate 4
mmalcam_secondary_buffer_upscale 5
pre_capture 4
output_both_pictures on
output_secondary_pictures on
target_dir /run/shm
snapshot_filename lastsnap
picture_filename preview
movie_filename %Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

**NOTE:** The distro used above is Raspian.

Further in that thread this comment is also key:

> You should be getting the video at 640x480 and the stills at 2560x1920.

There's another link to how to set up MMAL - [Re: Motion - MMAL camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=864996#p864996).